# Anyway to automatically convert DWF to PDF?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, autocad

Our eTendering solution, www.monaqasat.com, currently works exclusively with PDF documents for various reasons, some of them being security. We are being asked if we can support DWF documents. For this to happen, we would need to find a way to automatically convert DWF documents to PDF, using some kind of Unix application.

Does anybody know any such application, preferably using Rails or Java?

Thanks,

.Karim

Answer (score 1):

http://www.autodwg.com/pdf/

http://www.dwgto.com/

http://www.aidecad.com/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PDF_software

http://www.cogniview.com/convert-pdf-to-excel/category/pdf/

Suggestion would be to install a software printer call its APIs and pass dwf and get back pdf and then apply security as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it needs to be a Linux application since our application is Linux based...

Comment: AutoCAD is for windows, so not much use cases to have a converter for Linux.Why in the first place should your application convert a DWG to PDF? Why can't you tell the user of your system to buy a software and convert it to PDF and then add it to your system as attachment.This way you save the trouble and cost of developing something new.Also the end user can use his Windows env to print it as PDF and you can just apply your security on that PDF.

Comment: Also AutoCAD could have an option to generate to PDF or you can install free Printers like PrimoPDF and try.AutoCAD support print to Postscript or JPG means you just need to convert that to PDF again using the printer software.

Answer (score 1):

Autodesk has its DWF Toolkit available at

http://www.autodesk.com/dwftoolkit

It contains full source code in C++ to read & write DWF files, so it should be reasonably easy to make it run under Linux and to use a PDF library to write the output.